# List.sort with two fields

Tags: java, arraylist, lambda

I saw this code on leetcode discussion section, but I was not able to understand it. please help here.

```
HashMap<Character,Integer> map = new HashMap<>();
    for(char ch: s.toCharArray()){
        map.put(ch,map.getOrDefault(ch,0)+1);
    }
    List<Character> list = new ArrayList<>(map.keySet());//convert hashmap keys into list
    list.sort((x,y) -> map.get(y) - map.get(x));
```

Im not able to understand the meaning of the below line.

**list.sort((x,y) -> map.get(y) - map.get(x));**

Comment: What specifically is not clear? Are you familiar with lambdas syntax (the `... -> ...` notation)? Are you familiar with Comparators?

Comment: note that `x - y` is an (unfortunately popular) anti-pattern. it yields incorrect results on underflow/overflow situations. the better way to implement is by `Integer.compare(x, y)` or explicitly with `x < y ? -1 : (x == y ? 0 : 1)`. it is even faster if the numbers are big.

Answer (score 6):

There is actually a surprising number of things going on with that one short line: `list.sort((x,y) -> map.get(y) - map.get(x));`.

## `List.sort( Comparator comparator )`

The [`List.sort`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/util/List.html#sort(java.util.Comparator)) method takes a [`Comparator`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/util/Comparator.html) object as an argument.

## `@FunctionalInterface`

If you look at the `Comparator` interface, you’ll see that it is annotated by [`@FunctionalInterface`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/FunctionalInterface.html). To quote the Javadoc, “Conceptually, a functional interface has exactly one abstract method.”.

## Lambda

This code:

```
(x,y) -> map.get(y) - map.get(x)
```

… is lambda syntax that acts as an implementation of that single abstract method.

That lambda is written with compact syntax. You might find the expanded format to be explanatory.

```
( String x , String y ) -> { return map.get( y ) - map.get( x ); }
```

… as in:

```
list.sort( ( String x , String y ) -> { return map.get( y ) - map.get( x ); } );
```

The compiler knows to expect a `Comparator` object as the argument to `List#sort`. So,  **the compiler can infer this lambda-implemented method** is meant to be the [`compare`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/util/Comparator.html#compare(T,T)) method of `Comparator`, the only abstract method found on `Comparator`.

## `Comparator#compare`

The `Comparator#compare` method returns an `int` integer number. To quote the Javadoc: that returned number means “a negative integer, zero, or a positive integer as the first argument is less than, equal to, or greater than the second.”.

The value side of the key-value pairings in your [`HashMap`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/util/HashMap.html) is of the type [`Integer`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/Integer.html) class. So merely subtracting one value `Integer` object from another is a seemingly clever way to determine the integer number to be returned by the `compare` number.

## Integer overflow

⚠️ However, as [commented below](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73429774/list-sort-with-two-fields/73429816#comment129674806_73429816), the above approach is **mathematically flawed**. The subtraction could result in an [integer overflow](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Integer_overflow).

### `Integer.compare`

Better to delegate the comparing work to a method found in the `Integer` class: [`Integer.compare`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/Integer.html#compare(int,int)).

```
( x , y ) -> Integer.compare( x , y )
```

Example code:

```java
// Source of data.
final Map < String, Integer > map =
        Map.of(
                "Alice" , 42 ,
                "Bob" , 2 ,
                "Carol" , 7
        );
System.out.println( "map = " + map );  // Be aware that a Map can iterate in any order at any time.

// Unsorted list.
final List < String > list = new ArrayList <>( map.keySet() );  // List may be built from a map in any order, given that a map iterates in no particular order.
System.out.println( "list = " + list );

// Sorted list.
list.sort( ( String x , String y ) -> { return Integer.compare( map.get( x ) , map.get( y ) ); } );
System.out.println( "list = " + list );
```

When run:

```
map = {Bob=2, Alice=42, Carol=7}
list = [Bob, Alice, Carol]
list = [Bob, Carol, Alice]
```

We see our list sorts as `Bob, Carol, Alice`, in the order of (42, 7, 2).

If curious about the implementation of that method, examine the open source [code on the OpenJDK project](https://github.com/openjdk/jdk/blob/master/src/java.base/share/classes/java/lang/Integer.java). Excerpt:

```
public static int compare(int x, int y) {
    return (x < y) ? -1 : ((x == y) ? 0 : 1);
}
```

### `Comparator.comparingInt`

An alternative is the use of a `Comparator` object returned by the static [`Comparator.comparingInt`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/util/Comparator.html#comparingInt(java.util.function.ToIntFunction)) method. Your IDE such as IntelliJ might even suggest this code.

```
list.sort( Comparator.comparingInt( list :: get ) )
```

That call to the static method `Comparator.comparingInt` returns a `Comparator` object. Just what we need to pass to the `List#sort` method.

The [`map :: get`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/util/Map.html#get(java.lang.Object)) part is a [method reference](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/methodreferences.html).

Example:

```java
// Source of data.
final Map < String, Integer > map =
        Map.of(
                "Alice" , 42 ,
                "Bob" , 2 ,
                "Carol" , 7
        );
System.out.println( "map = " + map );  // Be aware that a Map can iterate in any order at any time.

// Unsorted list.
final List < String > list = new ArrayList <>( map.keySet() );  // List may be built from a map in any order, given that a map iterates in no particular order.
System.out.println( "list = " + list );

// Sorted list.
list.sort( Comparator.comparingInt( map :: get ) );
System.out.println( "list = " + list );
```

## Reverse order

Your example code actually sorts the numeric order in *descending* order rather than *ascending* order.

If you want that effect, you can do so with another convenient method in the `Comparator` class: [`reversed`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/util/Comparator.html#reversed()).

Use [method-chaining](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Method_chaining) to append `.reversed`, like this: `Comparator.comparingInt( map :: get ).reversed()`.

```java
// Source of data.
final Map < String, Integer > map =
        Map.of(
                "Alice" , 42 ,
                "Bob" , 2 ,
                "Carol" , 7
        );
System.out.println( "map = " + map );  // Be aware that a Map can iterate in any order at any time.

// Unsorted list.
final List < String > list = new ArrayList <>( map.keySet() );  // List may be built from a map in any order, given that a map iterates in no particular order.
System.out.println( "list = " + list );

// Sorted list.
list.sort( Comparator.comparingInt( map :: get ).reversed() );
System.out.println( "list = " + list );
```

Results:

```
map = {Carol=7, Bob=2, Alice=42}
list = [Carol, Bob, Alice]
list = [Alice, Carol, Bob]
```

We see the new result `Alice, Carol, Bob` (42, 7, 2) is the opposite of the previous `Bob, Carol, Alice` (2, 7, 42).

## Auto-boxing

Also, the `map.get(y) - map.get(x)` part invokes [auto-boxing](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Boxing_(computer_science)).

Each `get` call returns an object of type `Integer` class. Using the subtraction sign `-` with `Integer` objects makes no sense directly; objects cannot be subtracted. However the compiler is smart enough to recognize that a `Integer` object can be converted to a `int` primitive. And two `int` primitives can be subtracted.

---

## Code point

By the way, `Character` class is a wrapper class for the `char` primitive type. Both have been essentially broken since Java 2, and legacy since Java 5. As a 16-bit value, a `char` is physically incapable of representing most characters.

Instead, when working with individual characters, learn to use [code point](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Code_point) integer numbers. Every one of the 144,697 characters defined in Unicode has been permanently assigned a particular number. The numbers range from zero to just over a million.

You will find `codePoint…` methods on classes such as `String`, `Character`, `StringBuilder`, and more.

Comment: note that `x - y` is an (unfortunately popular) anti-pattern. it yields incorrect results on underflow/overflow situations. the better way to implement is by `Integer.compare(x, y)` or explicitly with `x < y ? -1 : (x == y ? 0 : 1)`. it is even faster if the numbers are big.

Comment: @Zabuzard Thank you for that reminder. I worked your point into the Answer.

Answer (score 0):

You can use Go to Declaration in your IDE. ( Ctrl + B in Intellij for example) and see the method:

```
sort(Comparator<? super E> c)
```

So there are not 2 fields, is only one, a comparator as described in previous answer.

Maybe it would help you to read clear if you extract it as variable ( Ctrl + Alt + V in Intellij).

```
Comparator<Character> characterComparator = (x, y) -> map.get(y) - map.get(x);
```

Also in this case it can be simplified to :

```
Comparator.comparingInt(map::get)
```

So the sort would be:

```
list.sort(Comparator.comparingInt(map::get));
```